# AngularJS Promise Loop error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have a `configs` object. For each object in `configs`, I am looping and performing a call using $http.get (which is in SPARQLService). The `configs` object contains different object and thus doing different calls on different URLs. Within that loop, whenever I am getting the promise from the $http.get, in the `then` function I am updating an object found in $rootScope. The problem I am getting is that the `configs` contains different object but the object i am updating in rootScope all contains results for a similar object from the `configs`. A sample code:

```
 for (var config in configs ){
            var newConfig = configs[config];
            var data = SPARQLService.query(newConfig["endpointURL"],encodeURIComponent(newConfig["SPARQLQuery"]));
            var bindings;
            data.then(function (answer){
                sparql_result = answer.data;
                bindings = answer.data.results.bindings;

                //creating the markers
                markers = [];
                for (var binding in bindings){
                    currentBind = bindings[binding];
                    var latitude = currentBind[newConfig["lat"]].value;
                    var longitude = currentBind[newConfig["long"]].value;
                    var currentMarker = L.marker([latitude, longitude]);
                    currentMarker.bindPopup(Utilities.generateDescription(newConfig["desc"],currentBind));

                    markers.push(currentMarker);
                }
                $rootScope.config[newConfig["groupName"]] = newConfig;
                $rootScope.layers[newConfig["groupName"]] = L.layerGroup(markers);
                console.log($rootScope.config);

            },
                function (error){

            }); 

        }
```

Comment: Think your problem may be the `var newConfig` being declared outside the function that references it in the loop.  `newConfig` will be updated on each iteration of the loop but the reference to it is used in the functions that are asynchronously triggered, believe they will all be referencing the same `newConfig` at the time they execute... would verify this with the debugger with breakpoints where the newConfig is used to assign things to $rootScope.

Comment: but why is it that the newConfig object refer to the last object in configs ?

Comment: Well way I'm thinking of it is, when you do the .then call you give it a new function to call sometime in the future but it doesn't execute right then, you continue looping and updating the newConfig until you get done looping through all the configs and at that point newConfig points to the last thing, now the async http calls complete and the stack of callback functions start getting triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that `newConfig` within your `then` function is bound to the value of `newConfig` by reference, so when the promise finishes executing it will take whatever value is in `newConfig` at that time - not at the time the promise was invoked.

Every time the outer loop executes:

```
for (var config in configs ){
        var newConfig = configs[config];
```

`newConfig` will receive a new value, but it is not a new variable - in JavaScript the `for` loop is not a scope for variables, so `newConfig` actually belongs to the scope outside of the `for` loop, even though it is declared within there. When your `then` function accesses `newConfig` it is accessing the value that currently resides in this 'global' `newConfig` which is likely to be that from the final iteration of the loop (assuming the service call takes long enough for the loop to complete before a promise returns).

You need to somehow pass it through your service call so that it is available in the contents of `answer` in the `then` function.

Comment: Yup a local variable in the .then callback function will allow it to preserve the reference I'm pretty sure but this is basically what I was trying to say in the comments as well.